# When I add a number "a" into a set, it return with an error

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code that I can add many numbers into a set and then print it. I don't know why does it return an error. This is my code:

```
ask = int(input('How many numbers you want to add in a set?'))
sett = set()
while ask:
    a = int(input('Enter the number:')
    sett.add(a)
    ask = ask-1
    if ask == 0:
        print(sett)
        break
```

But it returned this error:
*‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎   File "Untitled5.py", line 5

    sett.add(a)

    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

So anyone can find why is it wrong? This question may be easy to answer but please answer.

Comment: You lack a closing parenthesis in the previous line. Voting to close as trivial typo.

Comment: You forgot to close a parenthesis: `int(input('Enter the number:'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to close a parenthesis:

```
ask = int(input('How many numbers you want to add in a set?'))
sett = set()
while ask:
    a = int(input('Enter the number:'))
    sett.add(a)
    ask = ask-1
    if ask == 0:
        print(sett)
        break
```